# MongoDB + Nodejs insert maximum length

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a large amount of text into a mongodb collection from nodejs. I've done some testing and found that the maximum length of the string can be only 49072. Here's how i do it:

```
 collection.insert({'largetext':POST["text"]});
```

Basically if I do a substring of (0, 49072) it works fine. (I can see the collection in mongodb). But if i do (0, 49073) then it just never appears in the db. There is no error either (I tried using {safe:true}, and using an error function to capture any errors...there weren't any).

I'm using http://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/ as my mongo driver.

Anyone have any clues what could be wrong here? I think it might be some Javascript maximum string length restriction, but if it is how do i still insert large text?

Thanks!

Comment: oh and by the way, my collections are not capped. db.collection.isCapped() == false.

Comment: Can you give a little more information about which version of mongodb you're using? A capped collection wouldn't effect this kind of thing but the maximum document size (not configurable, based on mongo version) might.

Comment: Sorry i'm using [initandlisten] db version v2.0.1, pdfile version 4.5

Comment: I encountered exactly the same problem as Felix did. I'm using the latest versions, node.js v0.8.1, MongoDB v2.0.6, node-mongodb-native v1.0.2. Simply could not insert a long string. Waiting for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a test in master that inserts a 50000 character string

https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/test/insert_test.js#L1180

passes without any problems so this might be a red herring and the problem could be somewhere else. I would suggest you try the test and see if it passes. also make sure you are on the latest node.js version and latest npm package.